# Running a Macro after refreshing data

Tags: vba, excel

I need to run a macro after some data in a table/pivot table is refreshed. My table is reading data from a database, so I want the macro to run after the refresh. How would I do this using VBA. I've tried the following.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal target As PivotTable)
    Application.Run "overrideManagers" 'Is this right?
End Sub
Sub overrideManagers() 'Macro to be run upon refresh of data
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

I don't get what was expected. I just get the refresh, but without the `MsgBox`. Even if I move the `MsgBox` to this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal target As PivotTable)
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

I get the same results. This leads me to think that my original method for catching the update is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the code for the `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` event on the sheet with the pivot table? It certainly works for me (the second code snippet).

Comment: I agree with @Ralph. You probably have the trigger event on the worksheet with the original data rather than the one with the pivot table. Ralph I would suggest you place this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a little lengthy answer. I'll try to explain clearly.

Below are the steps I followed

1. Created a new excel workbook with a simple table and data ( Sheet1)
2. Created a pivot table for that data ( Pivot table in another sheet - Sheet2)

[image]
3. Added the following code in Macro editor under Sheet2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
   MsgBox "update"
End Sub
```

4. Selected Sheet2, right click pivot table and refresh. Message box displayed
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: My Pivot table isn't reading data from another table. It's reading data from a database. Is there a different method for that refresh?

Comment: I just tried connecting to Access Database and the same above method worked just fine. As long as you refresh the pivot table, the event will get triggered.

Comment: I solved it by using just `Worksheet_Change()` on just some calculated field, but thanks for the answer.